# Pyside2でスロットが使えない

Tags: python, windows-10, pyside

現在pyside2でwebブラウザを作成しています。
toolbarのボタンで戻ったり、ページを読み込んだりしようとするのですが、スロットがうまく反応してくれません。

どなたか原因をご存じの方は教えていただきたいです。。

```
browser.py

import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, Slot
from PySide2.QtGui import QPainter
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QHeaderView, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts
from PySide2.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from toolbar import Browser_Toolbar

@Slot()
def load_page(page,toolbar):
        # page.setUrl(toolbar.url_box.text())
        print("show")

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("tutorial")
        self.toolbar = Browser_Toolbar()
        self.page = page()
        self.page.load(self.page.initial_url)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.page)


        self.addToolBar(Qt.TopToolBarArea,self.toolbar)
        self.toolbar.url_box.returnPressed.connect(load_page(self.page,self.toolbar))
        self.toolbar.go.clicked.connect(load_page(self.page,self.toolbar))
        self.toolbar.back.clicked.connect(self.page.back())
        self.toolbar.next.clicked.connect(self.page.forward())
        # self.page.setUrl(self.toolbar.url_box.text())




class page(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebEngineView.__init__(self)
        self.initial_url = "https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineView.html#more"

    # def load_page(self,url=None):
    #     if url:
    #         self.load(url)
    #     else:
    #         self.load(self.initial_url)
    #     self.show()



class widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.items = 0
        self._data = {"Water": 24.5, "Electricity": 55.1, "Rent": 850.0,"Supermarket": 230.4, "Internet": 29.99, "Bars": 21.85,"Public transportation": 60.0, "Coffee": 22.45, "Restaurants": 120}

        self.table = QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        self.table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.fill_table()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
toolbar.py


from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QHeaderView, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit,QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QToolBar)
class Browser_Toolbar(QToolBar):
    def __init__(self):
        QToolBar.__init__(self)
        self.back = QPushButton("back")
        self.next = QPushButton("next")
        self.reload = QPushButton("reload")
        self.url_box = QLineEdit(self)
        self.url_box.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.go = QPushButton("Go!")

        self.addWidget(self.back)
        self.addWidget(self.next)
        self.addWidget(self.reload)
        self.addWidget(self.url_box)
        self.addWidget(self.go)
```

実行結果↓
[image: 実行結果]

- slotデコレータをつけたり外したりしたが、print("show")が実行されるのがまちまち。
- permission type 13のエラーは調べたところ、問題外らしい。

#### 環境

windows10 home 64bit
AMD RYZEN 5
Python 3.7.5(vanilla)
Pyside2 == 5.13.2

以上です。
かなり急いでおります。どうか回答をよろしくお願いします！

Comment: `self.toolbar.go.clicked.connect(load_page(self.page,self.toolbar))` とされていますが、signal connect に渡すのは関数なので、これでは `load_page(self.page, self.toolbar)` の**実行結果**を渡してしまっています(戻り値がないので何も起きません)。例えば lambda 式を使って `self.toolbar.go.clicked.connect(lambda _: load_page(self.page,self.toolbar))`  としてみて下さい。

Comment: 今になって思い付いたのですが、`load_page` 関数を `MainWindow` クラスのメソッドにするのはどうでしょうか(`def load_page(self): self.page.setUrl(self.toolbar.url_box.text())` )。そうすれば `self.toolbar.go.clicked.connect(self.load_page)` とする事ができます。